# Angular toastr2 doesnt shows up

Tags: angular, toastr

So I am trying to do toastr in many ways but it's not working.
Heres doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-toaster?activeTab=readme
My HTML:

```
<button (click)="test()">Make a toast!</button>
```

MY TS:

```
import {ToasterService} from 'angular2-toaster';
```

constructor
(
private router: Router,
private toastr: ToasterService
) { }

```
 test() {
this.toastr.pop('success', 'Success', 'The Joke has been added');
```

}

App HTML:

```
 <toaster-container>

</toaster-container>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My app.module:

```
import { ToasterModule } from 'angular2-toaster';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    PagesModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NgbModule,
    CommonModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToasterModule.forRoot(),
  ],
```

Also in my angular.json have:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "./node_modules/angular2-toaster/toaster.css",
              "src/styles.css"
```

I Have no idea why that's not working. Any suggestions ?

Comment: Oh I added into css.: @import "~angular2-toaster/toaster.min.css";